# Show that if $A \subseteq B$ then $((B-A) \cup A) \subseteq B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I begin with:
"Let $x\in A$ then $x \in B$ (by hypotesis)".
...

But the fact "$\mathbf {x\in A}$ then $x \in B$" is really equivalent to "$((\mathbf{x\in B \land  x\notin A )\lor x\in A)} \Rightarrow x\in B$"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that "then" represents the conditional connector, then yes, it is equivalent. Use the definition of conditional based on $\vee$

Comment: Check also past links like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569340/prove-that-a-cup-m-setminusa-m?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $A \subseteq B$  and let $x \in ((B - A)\cup A)$. We have two cases:

1. $\underline{x \in B-A}$. In particular, since $B - A \subseteq B $, it follows that $x \in B$.
2. $\underline{x \in A}$. Since by assumption we have that $A \subseteq B$, it follows that $x \in B$.

In either case $x \in ((B - A)\cup A)$ implies that $x \in B$. But our choice of $x$ was arbitrary, so for any $x$ we have that  $$x \in ((B - A)\cup A) \implies x \in B,$$ so $((B - A)\cup A) \subseteq B$ by definition of "$\subseteq$", as required.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x\in B\wedge x\notin A)\vee x\in A,$ then $x\in B\vee x\in A$. But since $A\subset B,$  then $x\in B$.